# Why the frame of the UILabel in standard UITableViewCell is (0,0,0,0) and What's the Standard Size of UITableViewCell.textLabel?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I want to replace that with a webview so I can display html.

```
PO(cell.subviews);
PO(cell);
PO(cell.contentView.subviews);
```

The webview need to have the same frame with the frame of UITableViewCell.

This is what we got:

```
2013-01-31 12:37:35.204 BadgerNew[3888:c07] cell.subviews: (
    "<UITableViewCellContentView: 0xa057140; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0xa057180>>"
)
2013-01-31 12:37:35.204 BadgerNew[3888:c07] cell: <UITableViewCell: 0xa0c37a0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'atm'; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0c8530>>
2013-01-31 12:37:35.205 BadgerNew[3888:c07] cell.contentView.subviews: (
    "<UILabel: 0xa0d12a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'atm'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0571b0>>"
)
```

Moreover, to further confirm

```
po [cell textLabel]
(UILabel *) $1 = 0x0a0d12a0 <UILabel: 0xa0d12a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'atm'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0571b0>>
```

What is the final standard frame for normal UITableViewCell then?

I also did

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    PO(self);
    PO(self.textLabel);
    while (false);
}
```

and got

```
2013-02-01 09:36:02.048 BadgerNew[1436:c07] self.textLabel: <UILabel: 0x8923390; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x89e8fc0>>
```

Doing it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    while (false);
}
```

yield the same result

Then I did:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    PO(self);
    PO(self.textLabel);
    while (false);
}
```

Again, another 0 frame.

Comment: Use Custom cell if you want to change frame of label.

Comment: I don't want to change. I want to know

Answer (score 2):

The frames of the subviews within a cell are set after `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Make a subclass of UITableViewCell, it's really the best way of handling things like this. You can override `-textLabel` in your subclass and bend it to your will, or you can override `-layoutSubviews` and use `-textLabel`'s frame then.

One final warning, mucking around with the internals of an object causes brittle code that could break at any revision of iOS.

Comment: What is the final standard frame for normal UITableViewCell then?

Comment: Just to note, that you can get the actual frame of that label in this delegate method `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @iMartin That's not completely reliable. [`-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:): After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Comment: iMartin would you change that into an answer I just want to know the default size.

Comment: Actually no it doesn't work. I tried and the textLabel frame is still 0

Comment: @JefferyThomas I think that note is about frame and alpha **of the cell**, not subviews.

Comment: @JimThio Sorry for wrong info, other attributes and final in that method. In fact, implementation of `UITableView` is very old and sometimes have strange behavior. They should rewrite these ancient components.